# Create a file only if doesn't exists

Tags: c#, .net, io

I want to create a file ONLY if it doesn't already exists.
A code like:

```
if (!File.Exists(fileName))
{
    fileStream fs = File.Create(fileName);
}
```

Leave it open for a race-condition in case the file will be created between the "if" to the "create".

How can I avoid it?

EDIT:
*locks* can't be used here because it's a different processes (multiple instances of the same application).

Comment: same application ? mutex ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Kristian Fenn answer was almost what I needed, just with a different FileMode. This is what I was looking for:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.CreateNew);
```

Answer (score 23):

You can also use

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
```

However, you should look into thread locking as if more than one thread tries to access the file you'll probably get an exception.

Comment: MSDN does not state whether that constructor is threadsafe, so you're right to urge caution in a multithreaded environment.

Comment: Two threads both trying it concurrently will get the same results as [`CreateFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858(VS.85).aspx) (as `FileStream`'s constructor is a wrapper over Win32) being called concurrently – one thread will win. As I understand it, at a kernel level this is a single operation: one thread won't create while the other does the open.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. only with " FileMode.CreateNew" as the second parameter.

Comment: This opens the file even if it exists. That is exactly the opposite of what the OP is asking for. How can you tell if the file existed or not when using `FileMode.OpenOrCreate`? I imagine someone saying “check [`FileStream.Length`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.isasync?view=netframework-4.7.2)”—but an existing file could easily have a `Length` of 0 too. The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20512866) is the correct one…

Answer (score 2):

Is this not a better solution. Also notice the `using(var stream...)` Use it to close the stream to avoid IO Exceptions.

```
if (!File.Exists(filePath))
{
    using (var stream = File.Create(filePath)) { }
}
```

Comment: The OP explicitly requested that the race condition be closed. [`File.Create(string)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.file.create?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_File_Create_System_String_) is equivalent to `new FileStream(myPath, FileMode.Create)`. [`FileMode.Create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.filemode?view=netframework-4.7.2) truncates existing files (unlike `FileMode.CreateNew` which is what the OP wants because it avoids the race condition).

Answer (score 0):

If the contending attempts to create the file are in the same process, you can use a `lock` statement around your code to prevent contention.

If not, you may occasionally get an exception when you call File.Create.  Just appropriately handle that exception.  Checking whether the file exists before creating is probably advisable even if you are handling an exception when the file does exist because a thrown exception is relatively expensive.  It would not be advisable only if the probability of the race condition is low.

Comment: I hope you don't write any of the software that I use.  Guaranteed safety above guesswork, please.

Answer (score 0):

First you Lock or Monitor.Enter or TryEnter APIs to lock the portion of the code.
Second you can use FileStream API with FileMode.OpenOrCreate API. If the file exists, it just uses it or else it just creates it.